# File transfer to SMB (Ubuntu 18.04 => Synology 718+) very slow

Tags: samba, file-transfer, synology, ubuntu-18.04

I have Synology DS718+, which I am testing with one user (myself) currently.

My transfer rates from my laptop to Synology of around 2 MB/s. 
**However copying FROM Synology back to laptop is around 30 MB/s!** - therefore I am ruling network issues out.

Synology is connected directly to a router (1000Mbps) with a cat6 cable. Also in the control panel the interface setting show 1000Mbps, full duplex. Laptop is connecting using WiFi, so I don't expect 1GB, but 2MB is a bit extreme.

My laptop is Ubuntu 18.04, interface set to 1000Mb.

SMB is enabled with SMB2 to SMB3.
If I disable SMB Transport Encryption Mode I SOMETIMES get to whooping 3 MB/s

I am about 5m from the router, no walls etc. in the way.

**EDIT:**

As per Freddy's suggestion (thanks Freddy) I tried different file sizes - always looks similar. However I noticed the speed is increasing very slowly - this can be seen clearly when copying larger file, i.e. 3GB. The file started as always at 2MB and by the end of the copying process transfer rate was ~7.5 MB.

Transfer rates over FTP are exactly the same - very slow copying to Synology and 10-12x faster copying from.

Comment: Have you tried disabling wifi and connecting the laptop via cable only? Just to rule out that wifi is the bottleneck. What are the transfer rates with cable?

Comment: @Freddy I am planning to do it, don't have a cable right now. But note that I mentioned I have 10x better reading transfer rates (text in bold). Therefore it looks to me like SMB configuration issue more than network.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "to rule wifi out". But it would be interesting to see if the transfer rate to the Synology stays at ~2MB/s with cable while the other direction gets (hopefully) a lot faster. Another thing you could test: Is the performance about the same when copying files with different file sizes (1MB, 10MB, 100MB, 1GB)? It sounds like your Synology behaves like a cheap usb3.0 thumb drive -- writes terribly slow, but reads are okay.

Comment: Are ftp transfer rates about the same?

Comment: Yes, the same. I also noticed another funny behavior. I was copying a bigger file (3GB) and the transfer rate was slowly going up. By the end of the file it got to 7.5MB (started at 2MB as always).

Comment: Wow, direct memory access in full effect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. It should have been posted on askubuntu, but I didn't know at the time of posting...

Long story short, it was my laptop. ***I upgraded the kernel from 4.15 generic to 4.20*** - that's it. I suspect my WiFi card (Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174) doesn't work well on the factory kernel.

**How did I get there:**

I started testing with another laptop with W10, which was working very well. So I knew it was not network/SMB config/Synology. So I was trying to set up manual network negotiation mode between my ubuntu laptop and Synology, but I realized my wifi card doesn't give me a lot of configuration options. For example this is what ethtool shows for my card:

```
$ sudo ethtool wlp2s0
Settings for wlp2s0:
        Link detected: yes
```

Also dmesg was showing some failures, which unfortunately I don't have to paste anymore.

I started looking for a better driver and ended up installing ukuu and upgrading kernel. Initially I installed 4.20, which worked perfectly, but I had to downgrade to 4.18, because 4.20 has problems with DisplayLink/Evdi, which I use as well. But I confirm that 4.18+ fixes the issue.

Hope this helps somebody.